# How to extract the second part of the string after the backslash in R?

Tags: r, string, backslash, metacharacters

I have a string 'ABC1\001ABCEFCGJS'
I want to extract only 001ABCEFCGJS from this string
How to do so in R?
My String will be a dynamic string.
So the solution should be such that function can read anything after backslash.

Comment: Can you share your string using `dput` ? Do you need `sub(".*\\\\", '','ABC1\\001ABCEFCGJS')` ?

Comment: My String is str<-'ABC1\001ABCEFCGJS'

Comment: If that is your string then it does not have any backslash. Print `cat(str)` to see the actual string.

Comment: yes but can you please suggest how to extract '001ABCEFCGJS' this part of the string from my original string ('ABC1\001ABCEFCGJS')?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to convert to `raw` and then remove the elements, while appending the correct raw value for '001'

```
rawToChar(c(charToRaw('001'),charToRaw(str1)[-(1:5)]))
#[1] "001ABCEFCGJS"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- 'ABC1\001ABCEFCGJS'
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply,but my string will be a dynamic one. So my purpose is to extract anything in a string after the backslash.